# Stub Request is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, request, stub, webmock

This webmock stub request is not working while running the test. Here is the controller.

```
class AdvisorDashboardController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource :class => AdvisorDashboardController
  require 'Numeric.rb'
  include ApplicationHelper

  def index   
      process_equity_data
      # Get transaction details from OP service
      @indices_data = MarketDatum.where("category = 'Indices'")
      @transactions = Service.new(session_email: current_user.email, user: current_user.user_id).latest_transactions
      unless @transactions.blank?
        @transactions.each do |transaction|
          case transaction['order_type']
          when 'PENDING'
            @pending_transaction =  transaction
          when 'SEMI_SETTLED'
            @semi_settled = transaction
          when 'SETTLED'
            @settled = transaction
          end
        end
        if !@transactions.blank? && @pending_transaction.blank? && !@semi_settled.blank?
          @active_transactions = @semi_settled['order_count'].to_i
        elsif !@transactions.blank? && !@pending_transaction.blank? && @semi_settled.blank?
          @active_transactions = @pending_transaction['order_count'].to_i
        elsif !@transactions.blank? && !@pending_transaction.blank? && !@semi_settled.blank?
          @active_transactions = @pending_transaction['order_count'].to_i + @semi_settled['order_count'].to_i
        end
      end
      unless session[:service_config].blank?
        rows_m2id = []
        service_code = helpers.service_type(Constant::TDREMINDER, session[:service_config])
        unless service_code.blank? && service_code['service_provider'].blank?
           @term_deposit = OrderpadService.new(session_email: current_user.email, service_code: service_code['service_provider'], advisor_id: current_user.user_id).term_deposit
            if !@investers_list.blank?
            @investers_list.each do |investor_m2id|
              rows_m2id << investor_m2id['m2id']
            end
          end
         @term_deposit = OpenTdList.select('open_td_list_id, investor_entity_m2id, external_entity_id, investor_search_name, asset_m2id, asset_name, asset_reference, issuer_name, market_value, holding_ccy, maturity_date')
                                      .where("external_entity_id IN (?)", rows_m2id)
        end
      end

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.csv do
          log('info', current_user.email, 'File creating for transaction list..')
          headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="transaction-list"'
          headers['Content-Type'] ||= 'text/csv'
        end
      end
      log('info', current_user.email, 'retrieving market indices..')
      @indices_data = MarketDatum.where("category = 'Indices'")
  end

  def process_equity_data
    # Get availbale funds
    @equity_api = Service.new(session_email: current_user.email, user: current_user.user_id).equity_lists
    unless @equity_api.blank?
      log('info', current_user.email, 'retrieving market indices..')
      @watchlist_equity = MarketDatum.select('market_data.code, wat.created_at,market_data.updated_at')
                                     .joins('JOIN watchlists wat ON wat.code = market_data.code')
                                     .where('wat.created_by = ? AND market_data.status = 1', current_user.email)
                                     .order('wat.created_at DESC')
      log('info', current_user.email, 'retrieving watchlists..')
      @advisor_equity = Watchlist.where('created_by = ?', current_user.email)
      if !@advisor_equity.blank?
        @list = @advisor_equity.map(&:code)
        unless @equity_api.blank?
          @watchlist_equity_api = @equity_api.reject { |x| @list.include? x['code'] }
        end
      else
          @watchlist_equity_api  = @equity_api
      end

    end
  end

end
```

Here is the Rspec Controller

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe AdvisorDashboardController, type: :controller do
  login_dg_advisor
  let(:users) {  create :user, :users_list  }
  let(:watchlist) { create :watchlist, :equity  }

  describe 'GET #index' do
    it 'success' do
      expect(response).to be_success
    end

    it 'successfully renders the index template' do
      get :index, params: { called_by: 'index', id: users.user_id }

      expect(response).to render_template(:index)
    end

    context 'index with no ajax' do
      before(:each) do
        response =  '[
                          {
                            "order_id": "12",
                            "order_type": "PENDING",
                            "order_count": 103
                          },
                          {
                            "order_id": "13",
                            "order_type": "SEMI_SETTLED",
                            "order_count": 2
                          },
                          {
                            "order_id": "14",
                            "order_type": "SETTLED",
                            "order_count": 41
                          }
                       ]'

        uri_template = Addressable::Template.new "https://dev-alb-xxx.yyyyyyy.com.au/api/advisor?type=latest_transactions&advisor_id={id}"

        stub_request(:get, uri_template).
            with(headers: {'auth-token'=> 'f940625eb8139da7c50bfe39e85e0e7366fdslgkjdflgkjdfdlfkgjfdb97115029233933e19f02541f57db78b6356183b7d04116b937af3fae81f1cfddb606'}).
            to_return(status: 200, body: response, headers: {})
      end

      it 'successfully renders the index template' do
        get :index, params: { id: users.user_id,created_by: 'arvind@gmail.com' }
        expect(response).to render_template(:index)
      end
    end

    context 'pending trasnactions blank and semi-settled not blank' do
      before do
        response =  '[
                          {
                            "order_id": "13",
                            "order_type": "SEMI_SETTLED",
                            "order_count": 2
                          },
                          {
                            "order_id": "14",
                            "order_type": "SETTLED",
                            "order_count": 41
                          }
                       ]'

        uri_template = Addressable::Template.new "https://dev-alb-xxx.yyyyyyy.com.au/api/advisor?type=latest_transactions&advisor_id={id}"

        stub_request(:get, uri_template).
            with(headers: {'auth-token'=> 'f940625eb8139da7c50bfe39e85e0e7366fdslgkjdflgkjdfdlfkgjfdb97115029233933e19f02541f57db78b6356183b7d04116b937af3fae81f1cfddb606'}).
            to_return(status: 200, body: response, headers: {})
      end

      it 'successfully renders index template' do
        get :index, params: { called_by: 'market_indices', id: users.user_id, created_by: 'arvind@gmail.com' }
        expect(response).to render_template(:index)
      end

    end

    context 'pending trasnactions not blank and semi-settled is blank' do
      before do
        response =  '[
                          {
                            "order_id": "12",
                            "order_type": "PENDING",
                            "order_count": 103
                          },
                          {
                            "order_id": "14",
                            "order_type": "SETTLED",
                            "order_count": 41
                          }
                      ]'

        uri_template = Addressable::Template.new "https://dev-alb-xxx.yyyyyyy.com.au/api/advisor?type=latest_transactions&advisor_id={id}"

        stub_request(:get, uri_template).
            with(headers: {'auth-token'=> 'f940625eb8139da7c50bfe39e85e0e7366fdslgkjdflgkjdfdlfkgjfdb97115029233933e19f02541f57db78b6356183b7d04116b937af3fae81f1cfddb606'}).
            to_return(status: 200, body: response, headers: {})
      end

      it 'successfully renders index template' do
        get :index, params: { called_by: 'market_indices', id: users.user_id, created_by: 'arvind@gmail.com' }
        expect(response).to render_template(:index)
      end

    end

  end
end
```

The above three stub requests are not working. Instead the api call is called from the controller and I get an empty array as the response. Is there anything wrong with the stub request that I am using? Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: where in your controller is this called? `"https://dev-alb-xxx.yyyyyyy.com.au/api/advisor?type=latest_transactions&advisor_id={id}"` You were stubbing it in your specs so I assume that at some point in your controller, you were doing such a request on that url, but I couldn't see where you used it at least on what's shown on your controller code above. Please update your question then afterwards, and add the code where you are calling that URL from your controller.

Comment: here..
@transactions = Service.new(session_email: current_user.email, user: current_user.user_id).latest_transactions

Comment: In of your rspec `it` example above, can you temporarily comment out stubbing the request? And temporarily insert this line `WebMock.disable_net_connect!` just above `get :index, params: {........` then rerun rspec for that particular `it` example. You should see an rspec error message like `WebMock::NetConnectNotAllowedError: ...  You can stub this request with the following snippet:`. Then can you add that error message as part of your question. That would be helpful to us, so we can know the exact format of the request.

Comment: tried what you said and got this error..
**WebMock::NetConnectNotAllowedError: Real HTTP connections are disabled. Unregistered request: GET**

Comment: What other details of the error? Like is there something like `You can stub this request with the following snippet:`?

Comment: yes got that You can stub this request with the following snippet content

Comment: Yes, please do show us all of the error message, specifically the details of the request that has been blocked like the URL and params or even headers. This will give us an idea of the actual request performed by the controller as it may (possibly) be different that your current `stub_request`, because we can only guess what your `Service` class does. Just replace/filter out any "sensitive" data / params of the error message before showing us the details.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147237/discussion-between-ganesh-kumar-and-jay-ar-polidario).

Answer (score 1):

`stub_request` stubs requests made via the `net/http` library, however Typhoeus, which you're using to make requests, wraps libcurl.  Beacuse of that, rather than `stub_request` you need to be using `Typhoeus.stub(...)` to stub those requests - https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus#direct-stubbing

Comment: Thomas is right. Didn't notice it in the documentation, but hopefully the following should work: `response_body =  '[
  {
    "order_id": "12",
    "order_type": "PENDING",
    "order_count": 103
  },
  {
    "order_id": "13",
    "order_type": "SEMI_SETTLED",
    "order_count": 2
  },
  {
    "order_id": "14",
    "order_type": "SETTLED",
    "order_count": 41
  }
]' \n response = Typhoeus::Response.new(code: 200, body: response_body) \n Typhoeus.stub('https://dev-alb-xxx.yyyyyyy.com.au/api/advisor').and_return(response)`

Comment: @GaneshKumar as just what Thomas said, Webmock `stub_request` uses a different library, which would then not "capture" and mock the request, if using Typhoeus requests. I cannot verify this though as I haven't used Typhoeus, but this is what I take and understood.

Comment: seems like Webmock works on Typhoeus requests. Try copying my code snippet http://code.runnable.com/WUuhtXLNnz93uoMy/proof-that-webmock-works-on-typhoeus-requests-for-ruby